# Want to find a better solution than loop searching sql table(oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, datatable, solution

I have a table as follows.

I only know the value of the first from_field, and need to deduce which row the last to_field is.
For example, it is known that the starting point is 1a in the from_field field, so the next one is 2a in the to_field field, and then from 2a in the from_field field to 3a in the to_field field, the path is as follows:

1a -> 2a -> 3a -> 4a -> 5a

When the value of the type field is end, it means that the row is the last row.

| from_field | to_field | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 2a | path |
| 2a | 3a | path |
| 3a | 4a | path |
| 4a | 5a | end |
| 1b | 2b | path |
| 2b | 3b | end |
| 1c | 2c | end |

This table has tens of thousands of rows. I currently use a loop to search for the rows repeatedly to find the last to_field, but it takes a lot of time.
Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a hierarchical query. Sample data in lines #1 - 10; query begins at line #11.

```
SQL> with test (from_field, to_field) as
  2    (select '1a', '2a' from dual union all
  3     select '2a', '3a' from dual union all
  4     select '3a', '4a' from dual union all
  5     select '4a', '5a' from dual union all
  6     --
  7     select '1b', '2b' from dual union all
  8     select '2b', '3b' from dual union all
  9     select '1c', '2c' from dual
 10    )
 11  select from_field,
 12         the_last_to_field
 13  from (select connect_by_root from_field   as from_field,
 14               from_field                   as the_last_to_field,
 15               connect_by_isleaf            as leaf
 16        from test
 17        connect by from_field = prior to_field
 18        start with from_field = '&par_from_field'
 19       )
 20  where leaf = 1;
Enter value for par_from_field: 1a

FROM_FIELD      THE_LAST_TO_FIELD
--------------- -----------------
1a              4a

SQL> /
Enter value for par_from_field: 3a

FROM_FIELD      THE_LAST_TO_FIELD
--------------- -----------------
3a              4a

SQL> /
Enter value for par_from_field: 1b

FROM_FIELD      THE_LAST_TO_FIELD
--------------- -----------------
1b              2b

SQL> /
Enter value for par_from_field: 1c

FROM_FIELD      THE_LAST_TO_FIELD
--------------- -----------------
1c              1c

SQL>
```